# Shell for only changing password

Tags: password, pam, passwd, shadow-utils

I need to restrict all access to a user on a RHEL 8 system and allow them to only change their own password.
I thought that I could do

```
[root]$ usermod <username> -s /bin/passwd
```

but this is not working.  What am I missing?

Update:

To be clear, the behavior is that, once the machine boots (multi-user.target) and you see that screen where you enter first your user name and then the prompt changes to ask for the password, if you enter the user for which I set the shell to either `/bin/passwd` or `/usr/bin/passwd` (and either via `vipw` straight into `/etc/passwd` or via `usermod`), the screen resets and in a split second it's back again to ask for a user name, as if nothing had happened.  Everything else is unchanged; with root, it just continues to work as normal.

Comment: That "/bin/passwd" is not a shell.

Comment: Are you trying to login with a GUI or text console?  What happens if you try to `ssh` in as that user?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to replace the shell in `/etc/passwd` file with `/usr/bin/passwd` or whatever is the path to your `passwd` command.  You can do that by using the command `vipw`.  I am not sure if `chsh` will allow you to change to a non-shell binary in that field.

`usermod -s` is also looking for an *approved* shell and `/bin/passwd` is obviously not an approved shell.

Comment: btw what's an "approved" shell?

Comment: An approved shell is one that the user can change to.  You can get a list by using the command `chsh -l`.